# Уменьшить размер блока

Tags: css

Есть кнопки, оформленные в виде тега "а". 
Нужно чтобы размер одних кнопок немного отличался от других (в общем, другой размер задать). Но проблема, что эти кнопки находятся внутри того id, для которого уже прописан размер кнопок. Как им задать новый размер?
Насчёт кода, не знаю что кидать, у меня там куча всякой фигни которую я не очень то и понимаю. Цвет вот меняется, а размер не получается.

Comment: `#block .btn1 {style};`  и `#block .btn2{onother style} `так нельзя ?

Comment: Оно перекрывалось в итоге этим правилом, добавил "!important" и всё заработало.

Comment: important не надо - так как должно работать без него